# xcode commit and transfer breakpoints from one computer to another computer

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I'm looking a way to keep breakpoint settings between two computers with Xcode under github.
Addin that file:
server:myproject.xcodeproj alex$ ls xcuserdata/alex.xcuserdatad/xcdebugger/
Breakpoints.xcbkptlist

has no success.
Where i'm wrong?

UPDATE - it's working now, but i need to restart Xcode to see updated breakpoints. any chances to avoid it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're trying to share through git, you probably have `*.xcuserdatad` ignored (if not, you should). If you don't mind everyone seeing the breakpoint, you can share it from within Xcode:

Right-click the breakpoint in the breakpoint navigator and select "Share":

[image]

You should now be able to add the file via git. It'll be in a location like this:

```
Test/Test.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcdebugger/Breakpoints.xcbkptlist
```

Anybody else working on the project should now be able to use that breakpoint.

Comment: same result - i need to re-open Xcode project to see changes after pull, my method is easiest, don't necessary to moving breakpoints